# Band-limited double-step Fresnel diffraction for images with radio waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction

Is it possible to use [band-limited double-step Fresnel diffraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) to assemble a [holographic image with radio waves](http://www.opticsinfobase.org/oe/viewmedia.cfm?uri=oe-21-7-9192&seq=0)? If not is there a simular principle?

Comment: Are you referring to the methods that radio astronomers are using to reconstruct an "optical image" from band-limited, sparsely sampled measurements of the phase of a radio signal from distant astronomical sources? My best guess is that the answer is "yes", but maybe I am missing a specific detail you are asking about?

Comment: @CuriousOne no as best i understand those images are not diffracted but broadcast by the original object see my new link

Comment: The band-limitation and the diffraction occur in the instruments themselves. The resolution of a telescope is always limited by its aperture. In case of a radio telescope array, the limiting aperture is essentially a small number of small openings in a much larger effective aperture (the greatest distance in the array). As a result, the reconstructed images are heavily distorted by the actual distribution of telescopes, which one has to take into account during the data analysis. The side lobe structure which determines the amplitude sensitivity is a complex function.

Comment: In case of the scanner the aperture is given by the total scanned area and the size of the pixels. The demonstrated design doesn't seem to have any visible advantages over a direct imaging device, which reconstructs an image with a lens. Having said that, there are cases where such design are advantageous and/or the only solution to the imaging problem, as in case of gamma ray imaging problems, for which lenses can't be made. And having said that, it sounds like an interesting experiment. Good luck with your version!